# Can you compare a string to a "template" string using grep?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my @array = (
   'There were \d* errors that occurred',
   'Your system exploded because \.*',
);

my $error = 'There were 22 errors that occurred';
if (grep(/$error/, @array)) {
   print 'That error is ok, continue...';
} else {
   die;
}
```

Is there any way in perl to compare a full string to a string containing regex?
Like in this example I'd want both $error = 'There were 22 errors that occurred' and $error = 'There were 12341235 errors that occurred' to be compared to a kind of "template" string and have a boolean returned if it matches. Using grep is probably not possible, I guess.

Maybe something like this that actually works:

```
my @s = ('there were \d* errors');

print _error_checker(@s, 'there were 10 errors');

sub _error_checker {
    my (@acceptable_errors, $text) = @_;

    foreach my $error (@acceptable_errors) {
        if ($text =~ /$error/) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close,  you just need to invert your testing in the grep.

```
my @ok_errors = (
   'There were \d* errors that occurred',
   'Your system exploded because \.*',
);

my $errmsg = 'There were 22 errors that occurred';
if (grep {$errmsg =~ /$_/} @ok_errors) {
   print 'That error is ok, continue...';
} else {
   die;
}
```

Additionally, you can cache the regular expressions using [`qr{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html)

```
my @ok_errors = (
   qr{There were \d* errors that occurred},
   qr{Your system exploded because \.*},
);

my $errmsg = 'There were 22 errors that occurred';
if (grep {$errmsg =~ $_} @ok_errors) {
   print 'That error is ok, continue...';
} else {
   die;
}
```

Comment: And likely they want anchored regular expressions, e.g. `qr{\AThere were \d* errors that occured\z}`

Comment: Adding the cache was a really nice touch. :)

Comment: @zx81 Thanks.   Honestly, the biggest reason to do that is not for speed, but to make the code more self-documenting.  It makes it a lot easier to recognize that array as a list of regular expressions when they are quoted with `qr{}`.   The potential speed improvement is just a secondary bonus.